# How to Extract Default Control Template In Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm wondering how I can extract (get a copy) of the Default Template of a given control using Visual Studio. I know this can be done with Expression Blend (right click a control, "Edit Template" -> "Edit a Copy...") which then copies the default control template in my Xaml. But can this be done with Visual Studio at all?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> 2015 update with clear instructions

In Visual Studio 2013, you can get the default `ControlTemplate` of a control in a few simple steps.

1. In the WPF designer, select the relevant control, or place the mouse cursor on the relevant control in the XAML.
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the Properties Window.
3. Open the *Miscellaneous* category to find the *Template* property, or type *Template* in the search field at the top of the Window.
4. Click on the little square to the right of the *Template* field and select the *Convert to New Resource...* option:

[image]

5. In the popup dialog, name the new `ControlTemplate` to be added and decide where you want it to be defined:

[image]

1. Click on the *OK* button.

EDIT >>>

In Visual Studio 2019 and later, this option seems to be disabled for some reason. A workaround can be found by right-clicking the control in the design view and selecting "Edit Template", then selecting "Edit a Copy...".

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped me out when I needed to get the control template for the DatePickerTextBox so I could remove the annoying inner border.

Comment: This is really great - thanks! Do you know if there is a way to similarly extract the full Style? The 'Convert to New Resource' command is disabled on the Style property.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon, were you running the solution at that point?  That's the only reason that I can think of that would result in the Convert to New Resource button being disabled.

Comment: The control disappears, because VS inserts an empty template: <ControlTemplate x:Key="templatePasswordBox" TargetType="PasswordBox"/>

Comment: These instructions stand correct for VS2017 as well.

Comment: This still works in VS2022, though the little square is now a cylinder with a drop-down arrow.

Answer (score 35):

From Visual studio - right click the control, choose properties,

In the properties window look for the Template Property and right click it,
choose Extract Value To Resource

That will create a copy of the template in the XAML for you to work on.

Comment: When I did this on a Textbox the Template property was disabled so I couldn't right-click on it.

Comment: @Jeff: Rightclick your element in the designer window (not in the Xaml-Code), then "Edit Template..." and "Edit a Copy..."

Answer (score 9):

Just to update this question, in VS 11 the XAML designer allows you to do this just like Expression Blend.

Comment: This is still true with VS 2012 released.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to keep in mind: if you already have a style defined somewhere that targets the given control then all of the above described options will be disabled. I had the following bit of code in my App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the `edit a copy...` and `convert to new resource...` options described in the other answers were disabled for my Button (which was defined in a completely different file). I commented out the above style code for Button and suddenly both options weren't disabled anymore.

Moral of the story: *VS won't generate a style containing a template copy for you if a style already exists for that element anywhere in your code.*

Answer (score 2):

In VS19 I wasn't able to do this through properties.

However, I was able to right click the control in design mode `Edit Template` and `Edit a Copy`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible. However, you can use [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091) to view the default template for a given control.

Comment: I used to use Show Me The Template but found that the templates would occasionally be missing some functionality, so have switched to using the templates found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Comment: Link is now broken