# Checkbox IsMouseOver wont work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, controltemplate

When i add this controltemplate my checkboxes disapear and only the checkbox text is shown. And when mouse is over the textbackground becomes red, how do i get my checkbox background red when mouse is over?

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="Checkbox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"          Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"        Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"                   Value="20,15,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"               Value="/Resources/Fonts/Source Sans Pro/#Source Sans Pro" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"                 Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"      Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxForegroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBackgroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"              Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBorderbrushColor}"/>


    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <CheckBox  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                    <ContentPresenter  />
                </CheckBox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: put the trigger as a Style.Triggers instead of ControlTemplate.Triggers

Comment: I get The member "triggers" is not acceciable or recongnigzed?

Comment: <Style>...<Style.Triggers><Trigger ...>...</Trigger></Style.Triggers></Style>

Comment: How do you declare the `CheckBox`? Does it explicitly reference the style?

Comment: Yes <Checkbox style={Dynamic.... MyCheckboxStyle}

Comment: I tried Style.triggers but it doesn't work, somebody who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for some properties (try `FontSize`, for example), but not for others. The default template for the `CheckBox` has triggers of its own, and they don't bother with such things as `TemplateBinding`s.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787361/wpf-combobox-default-controltemplate) tells you how to extract the default template for a `ComboBox`. Here is an excerpt which shows your problem:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter
            Property="Background"
            TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
            Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
        ...
    </Trigger>
    ...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Your best bet is probably to override the entire template. Happily, it isn't *too* complex...

---

1. Remove your own template.
2. [Follow the steps outlined in the post I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787361/wpf-combobox-default-controltemplate). That should give you a copy of the default `CheckBox` template.
3. Modify that copy. In particular, the `IsMouseOver` trigger that I excerpted: Change `{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}` to `Red`.

---

If this is still unclear, [see this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388429/how-to-set-mouseover-event-trigger-for-border-in-xaml).

Comment: Can you please explain, seems like i already done what you did? Sorry but im beginner in xaml

Comment: Thanks a alot Petter!, i had to copy the default checkbox template to make it work.

Comment: Do i do the same thing with expander? My round white expander button doesnt show in my OS. You know any solutions? @petter

Comment: Dunno -- you can post that as a new question, with whatever code/XAML isn't working as expected.