# How can I set the datacontext to property of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

Having this structure and a combobox:

```
public abstract class A: UserControl
{
     public string MachineName { get; protected set; }
     ...
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     private List<A> m_listA = new List<A>();

     public MainPanel()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
     
        cbMachines.ItemsSource = m_listA;
        cbMachines.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cbMachines.DisplayMemberPath = "MachineName";
     }
}
```

If I execute it I have the list of elements of the combobox perfectly filled but the selected one is empty and throws a binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' 
''Grid' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='Grid' (Name=''); target element is 
'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

It seems that, it takes the grid of "A" main control as datacontext
it seems that, it takes the main control as data context, but i need the usercontrol as datacontext.

How can i do this?

Comment: The error message doesn't have anything to do with the code you are showing here. Besides that, having a UserControl as data item looks odd. Class A should not be derived from UserControl.

Comment: The error is thrown by the combobox, and takes the grid as datacontext which is the first control of a class herited of A which is a Usercontrol. This was the unique way to inherit from a Usercontrol and a custom class.

Comment: First, using a property named "Name" causes problem by my side. Because, Name property exists on base FrameworkElement.
Second set cbMachines.IsEditable = true; 
With those, I didn't have any issues display selected item.

Comment: Also I forgot to say that you should set SelectedIndex asynchronously, like that:
cbMachines.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => cbMachines.SelectedIndex = 0));

Comment: Asigning the selected index synchronously works as asynchronouly, why do I need to be async? Secondly, making it editable works for me too, but i dont want to edit it... The "Name" is not the real name im goig to change it in the question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding area in default ComboBox template is this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

In this visual, you cannot set SelectionBoxItemTemplate, SelectionBoxItem, SelectionBoxItemStringFormat because they are **read only**.

According to [.NET Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) (Combobox.cs UpdateSelectionBoxItem method) it checks if current item is ContentControl. If so, it gets Content as SelectionBoxItem; ContentTemplate as SelectionBoxItemTemplate and ContentStringFormat as SelectionBoxItemStringFormat.

As UserControl derives from ContentControl; you can make it possible by setting ContentTemplate for class A like this:

```
<UserControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.MachineName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Or you can use a custom template for ComboBox to assign content like this:

```
Content="{Binding SelectedItem.MachineName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
```

To get the default combobox template [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787361/wpf-combobox-default-controltemplate).

Or you can do it on code behind:

```
cbMachines.ApplyTemplate();
var contentPresenter = cbMachines.Template.FindName("contentPresenter", cbMachines) as ContentPresenter;
System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem.MachineName") { Source = cbMachines });
contentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector = null;
```

There is no easier way, I'm afraid.