# How to remove default margin and header of panorama control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, panorama-control

I am designing a page which contains a panorama control to display some image. I want to remove header and make image expandable to whole panorama dimensions. So how can I remove default header and margin of panorama.

Comment: It's sort of a hack, but try putting everything inside of the Header instead of Content section.

Comment: You can also edit the Style template and override the Panorama Style with your new static resource [link 8825030](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can get you, you cannot remove the Header Title of Panorama Control in Windows Phone, it has to be defined.

To expand your screen to full panorama view you can add attribute

shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"

in your phone:PhoneApplicationPage element. This will hide the network, battery status etc from top of your page.