# How to extend xamoutlookbar theme in wpf?

Tags: wpf, themes, infragistics, wpf-style

ResourceDictionary includes following markup.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:flTheme1="Fluent;component/Themes/Office2010"
                    xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"
                    xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
                    xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
                    xmlns:igOB="http://infragistics.com/OutlookBar"
                    xmlns:igOutlookBar="http://infragistics.com/OutlookBar"
                    xmlns:igThemes="http://infragistics.com/Themes"
                    xmlns:igThemes3="clr-namespace:Infragistics.Windows.Themes;assembly=InfragisticsWPF4.OutlookBar.v14.1"
                    xmlns:igThemes4="clr-namespace:Infragistics.Windows.Themes;assembly=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v14.1"
                    xmlns:igThemes5="clr-namespace:Infragistics.Windows.Themes;assembly=InfragisticsWPF4.DockManager.v14.1"
                    xmlns:igWindows="http://infragistics.com/Windows"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dwm">

          <Style TargetType="{x:Type igOB:OutlookBarGroup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=igThemes3}" >
         <style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

How to extend XamOutlookBar Theme so that I can Override style of OutlookBarGroup and apply my style on it to change its background.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set the Background property of your groups:

```
<igOB:XamOutlookBar>
    <igOB:OutlookBarGroup Background="{StaticResource YourBrushResource}"/>
</igOB:XamOutlookBar>
```

If you'd like to create an implicit style, I'd still suggest you just override the Background property:

```
<Style TargetType="igOB:OutlookBarGroup" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igOB:OutlookBarGroup}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YourBrushResource}"/>
</Style>
```

And finally, if you want to modify the control template, you could extract it using Visual Studio as answered in [How to Extract Default Control Template In Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio)