# Where to Find the default wpf chart template?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm using WPFToolKit. I want to change the look of a wpf chart based on default chart style template.

I noticed a chart instance has some properties like `TitleStyle` `LegendStyle` `ChartAreaStyle` `PlotAreaStyle` I think modifing these properties will change the look of a chart.

Where to find these default style templates?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract default `ControlTemplate`s from Visual Studio directly:

1. In the WPF designer, select the relevant control, or place the mouse cursor on the relevant control in the XAML.
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the Properties Window.
3. Open the *Miscellaneous* category to find the *Template* property, or type *Template* in the search field at the top of the Window.
4. Click on the little square to the right of the *Template* field and select the *Convert to New Resource...* option:

[image]

5. In the popup dialog, name the new `ControlTemplate` to be added and decide where you want it to be defined:

[image]

6. Click on the *OK* button.

Taken from the [How to Extract Default Control Template In Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio/28212036#28212036) question.

Answer (score 2):

I just did some search on the internet and find a really useful resource from [here](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9999344). It's the updated version of WPFToolKit 3.5, adding lots of useful features, really appreciate the author's work:)

Download the source code, You could build/compile to get the updated (4.0) version of `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll`,

I found the default template in the source code, here it is:

Default Chart Template:

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:Chart">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                            <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                                <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                    <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                                </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

And other styles like:

Axis Style

```
    <Style TargetType="charting:DisplayAxis">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="TitleStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="MajorTickMarkStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Line">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="X2" Value="4" />
                    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="4" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLineStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Line">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:DisplayAxis">
                    <Grid x:Name="AxisGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <datavis:Title x:Name="AxisTitle" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Title Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="datavis:Title">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Legend Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="TitleStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,10" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="2">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <datavis:Title Grid.Row="0" x:Name="HeaderContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" IsTabStop="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Items" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Legend Item Style:

```
<Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="8" Height="8" Fill="{Binding Background}" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Everything you need is in the source code, such as default datapointstyle and so on. It realy helped me a lot!!!