# How to remove right separator in ribbonquickaccesstoolbar? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I have a problem with vertical line after Menu Items, guess it is some kind of separator between groups of menu items. I already tried to remove it for some time, but I have no idea where to find property to change it. I couldn't find any similar question in stackoverflow. Can anybody help with it?

Here is Xaml code and Image of line:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <my:Ribbon>
            <my:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <my:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Sth" />  
                    </Menu>
                </my:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </my:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
         </my:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Separator which I want to get rid of in QuickAccessToolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2J2O.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by editing the default `ControlTemplate` for the `QuickAccessToolBar` control. You can find out how to set this in a custom style for the `QuickAccessToolBar` in the [Styling the QuickAccessToolbar](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radribbonview/styling-and-appearance/styling-quickaccesstoolbar) page on the Telerik website. While I'm aware that this linked page is for Silverlight, I believe that you'll find that the process to follow is the same.

You can also find out how to extract the default `ControlTemplate` for any control in Visual Studio from my answer to the [How to Extract Default Control Template In Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio/28212036#28212036) question here on Stack Overflow. Once you have found the relevant `ControlTemplate`, just locate and remove the `Separator` element and set your custom (edited) `ControlTemplate` to be used as the value for the `QuickAccessToolBar.Template` property.

> Disclaimer: You *may* find that the `Separator` element is *outside* the `QuickAccessToolBar` element and is in fact part of the `Window` instead.

Comment: thanks for help, is it possible to do this in VS 2010? While using Extract Value to Resource... option Exception of type 'MS.Internal?Validate+Validation.Failure' is being thrown.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in 2010 unfortunately... back then, we had to use Blend to do it.