# How to change WPF Calender Month and Year color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to change WPF Calendar Month and Year  color  .Header color

Comment: Tried anything? Googled a bit? Some code already working?

Comment: Where do you display this Date ? Have you already tried to code sth ?

Comment: It is calendar control .I used selecteddate to get the date.My issue is change the header Month and Year color. I used WPF calendar control.Please help me to solve this .

Comment: "Do this for me" requests are not really welcome here. What exactly did you try to solve your problem and what exactly stopped you?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the ControlTemplate of the DatePicker Control

You can find [How to get default Control Template of a control in Visual Stuidio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio)

And then customize it to fit your needs

I also read that it was possible (and easier) with Blend