# Set text color for DatePicker in disabled state?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am using a lot of DatePickers in my C#/WPF application. The people who will be using this app. usually are old and have problems with seeing/reading. 
I need to change the pale color of the text to something darker so anyone can read the text in the DatePicker.

How and where can I do that?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I see only 4 color properties in **Brushes** section: Background, BorderBrush, Foreground and OpacityMask.

Or I should be doing this with code, set the Brush with code?

Comment: I would have guessed "Foreground" is the right one? Setting the Brush in code is nothing different than in designer, just that the code is at a different place.

Comment: Do they need to read things which are disabled? ;)

Comment: @Rekshino yes. The specific DatePickers are enabled and you can enter a value. Once you have filled the form these date pickers get disabled but should still be in view.

Comment: OK, I see. Then use the solution from Bruno V, it seams to be the only option, or you develop a custom control based on DatePicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Foreground` property sets the text of the `DatePicker` in an **enabled** state. When the `DatePicker` is **disabled**, the control template adds a semi-transparent overlay to the control.

You can find the default template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates). The overlay is defined in the **PART_DisabledVisual** `Grid`. To fix your issue, you can copy the entire ControlTemplate in your code and modify the two Rectangles with `Fill="#A5FFFFFF"` to `Fill="Transparent"`.

Comment: Bruno, I'm trying to implement the solution you recommended but I've been unable to do so thus far. I've never used a template or control template before, so I've been trying to figure that out first. It seems like the solution is to create <Window.Resources> in the XAML and define Styles there; however, when I try to copy-paste the style in the link you provided and running it as-is, the control turns into a broken version of the DatePicker. It does not look like it did originally. Could you provide additional insight?

Comment: I believe your approach is correct but Microsofts default templates are not up to date. You can extract the default Control Template for the `DatePicker` in Visual Studio as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio). Modifying the DisabledVisual colors as described in my answer should lead to the correct result.