# WPF get the default TextBox mouse over color

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, wpf-style

I would like to color a control in exactly the same color like is the default `TextBox`'s mouse over color (preferably theme-aware). e.g.

```
<Rectangle Fill={x:Static WhatDoIPutHere}/>
```

Under which key/resource can I access the color? In my current system it appears to be the `#ff7eb4ea` light blue, but none of the *Highlight*, *Control* or *Border* [System Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=netframework-4.8) seems to be of that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct! *MouseOver* `Border` color is `#FF7EB4EA`; which is under `TextBox.MouseOver.Border` key. I don't think you'll be able to access these *Resources* from outside. You can get these details from default `ControlTemplate` for `TextBox`. Which is

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If you using *Blend for Visual Studio*, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/modify-the-style-of-objects-in-blend?view=vs-2019) to know how to access default `Templates` of any control. If you're using *Visual Studio*, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212036/3799923).