# wpf: How to get rounded corners on ItemsPresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I have some markup (from a Telerik Control Template). In that markup there is an ItemPresenter-element. I would like it (or rather, the content of it) to have Rounded corners.

With a button, you can get away with this to get rounded corners

```html
<Button Content="Search" >
      <Button.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="Border">
              <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
          </Style>
      </Button.Resources>
  </Button>
```

But this does not work on ItemPresenter. How can I achive this?

Comment: You can't do it directly, because an ItemsPresenter isn't a Framework element, and thus doesn't have a template. It's used solely in other templates to say "put your content here". To do this you'll have to template whatever control the ItemsPresenter is in. If you [extract that template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio) and post it here then we should be able to help you.

Comment: What control are you trying to customize?

Comment: @Mark: okthats what I was dreading, its a telerik control., I havent found the content of it _(yet), I ll have a look

Comment: @mm8: RadTabbedWindow from Telerik, I want the tabs to be rounded iat the top corners (as in Chrome for example)

Comment: You should still be able to extract the template, check out [this article on the Tekerik site](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-editing-control-templates).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the tabs in the header of the `RadTabbedWindow`, you should define a custom `RadTabItem` style that you set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `RadTabbedWindow` to, e.g.:

```
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow ...>
    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadTabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadTabbedWindowTabItemStyle}">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="PinButtonVisibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter Property="CloseButtonVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...

</telerik:RadTabbedWindow>
```

If you want need to edit the `ControlTemplate`, which you most probably do to get rounded corners, you should be able to right-click on the control in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) to copy the default template into your XAML markup. You could then edit it as per your requirements by for example setting the `CornerRadius` property of the `Border` element.