# How change style of ScrollBar in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I'm trying to change the design of  the scrollbar to another design and I can't.

The current design is as follows:

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="Scrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" BorderBrush="#FFF72323" SmallChange="0.01" Height="32" Margin="0,16,20,32" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="1.471,0.469" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFDE7C7C" Foreground="#FFDE2525" OpacityMask="#FFF14949">
                <ScrollBar.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-33.014" Y="1.984"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </ScrollBar.RenderTransform>

            </ScrollBar>
```

[The current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWVZD.png)

[And I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siwjQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the control template and styles of the `ScrollBar` and adapt them. You can extract them using [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio) or [Blend](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/blend-support). Put them into your application resource dictionary or local control resources, to be able to access them from your `ScrollBar`. For your custom style adapting the `SolidColorBrush`es in the extracted assets below should be enough to achieve the desired result.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Border" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Glyph" Color="#606060"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Thumb" Color="#CDCDCD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Background" Color="#DADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Border" Color="#DADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb" Color="#A6A6A6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Background" Color="#606060"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Border" Color="#606060"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb" Color="#606060"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Border" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#BFBFBF"/>

<Style x:Key="RepeatButtonTransparent" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Border}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
   <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0"/>
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                  <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Row="1"/>
               <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineUpButton" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                  <Path x:Name="ArrowTop" Data="M 0,4 C0,4 0,6 0,6 0,6 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 7,6 7,6 7,6 7,4 7,4 7,4 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 0,4 0,4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}" Margin="3,4,3,3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
               </RepeatButton>
               <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsDirectionReversed="true" Grid.Row="1">
                  <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                     <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                  </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                  <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                     <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                  </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                  <Track.Thumb>
                     <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbVertical}"/>
                  </Track.Thumb>
               </Track>
               <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineDownButton" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                  <Path x:Name="ArrowBottom" Data="M 0,2.5 C0,2.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 3.5,4 3.5,4 3.5,4 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 3.5,6 3.5,6 3.5,6 0,2.5 0,2.5 z" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}" Margin="3,4,3,3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
               </RepeatButton>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}" Value="true"/>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}" Value="true"/>
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowBottom" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}" Value="true"/>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}" Value="true"/>
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowTop" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}" Value="true"/>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}" Value="false"/>
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowBottom" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}" Value="true"/>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}" Value="false"/>
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowTop" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowTop" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowBottom" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
         <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
         <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                  <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                     <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineLeftButton" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                        <Path x:Name="ArrowLeft" Data="M 3.18,7 C3.18,7 5,7 5,7 5,7 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 5,0 5,0 5,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 0,3.5 0,3.5 0,3.5 3.18,7 3.18,7 z" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}" Margin="3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                     </RepeatButton>
                     <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                           <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                           <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                           <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHorizontal}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                     </Track>
                     <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineRightButton" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                        <Path x:Name="ArrowRight" Data="M 1.81,7 C1.81,7 0,7 0,7 0,7 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 0,0 0,0 0,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 5,3.5 5,3.5 5,3.5 1.81,7 1.81,7 z" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}" Margin="3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                     </RepeatButton>
                  </Grid>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Finally, use the control template in your `ScrollBar` by applying the `ScrollBarStyle` style.

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="Scrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" BorderBrush="#FFF72323" SmallChange="0.01" Height="32" Margin="0,16,20,32" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="1.471,0.469" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFDE7C7C" Foreground="#FFDE2525" OpacityMask="#FFF14949" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle}">
    <ScrollBar.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="-33.014" Y="1.984"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ScrollBar.RenderTransform>
</ScrollBar>
```