# ListboxItems change color on mouse over with datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` that looks like:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="25" ItemsSource="{x:Static constants:AppsToInstall.AllApps}" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:InstallItem}">
         <Grid x:Name="Grid">
            <Border x:Name="PART_BORDER" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CanInstall}"></CheckBox>
                  <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
               </StackPanel>
            </Border>
         </Grid>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

I have added a data template that allows me to bind to the item source being passed in.

With all of that said I cannot seem to get this to change the color of the entire `ListBoxItem` when hovering over this.

Please see picture below:

[image: displaying how entire view doesn't show]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a case for editing the control template of a `ListBoxItem`. This type is the container that hosts your data template and it also defines the mouse over hover effect.

Just [extract the default control template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio) using Visual Studio or Blend. Both will extract the needed styles and resources, which you can put in your resource dictionary or control `Resources`.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

What you have to do now is to replace the `SolidColorBrush` for `Item.MouseOver.Background` with your color. Then, apply this style `ListBoxItemStyle` as the `ItemContainerStyle` in your `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         Margin="25"
         ItemsSource="{x:Static constants:AppsToInstall.AllApps}" SelectionMode="Multiple"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
   <!-- ...your XAML code. -->
</ListBox>
```

The result looks like this.

[image]