# WPF starter Button next to ToolBar tab but not inside

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, tabcontrol, controltemplate

I can not figure out how to get button `Razveljavi` to stay next to `Osnovno` and `Vstavi`. I don't want it to be in toolbar but on right side so it is shown all the time no matter which tab you are on.

There is a picture with what I got and how I want it to look. If anyone could help me that would be great. Im sure its just a small problem but I just started with WPF.

[image: Screenshot of the application]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <MenuItem Header="Datoteka">
            <MenuItem Header="Odpri"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Shrani"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Izhod" Click="izhod"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Uredi">
            
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Orodja">
            
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="Osnovno">
            <ToolBarTray>
                <ToolBar>
                    <Button Content="Pisava"/>
                    <Button Content="Barva" Click="spreminjanjeBarve"/>
                </ToolBar>
                <ToolBar>
                    <Button Content="Kopiraj" Click="kopiraj">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="Izreži"/>
                    <Button Content="Prilepi" Click="prilepi"/>
                </ToolBar>
                <ToolBar>
                    <Button Content="Razveljavi"/>
                    <Button Content="Ponovi"/>
                </ToolBar>
            </ToolBarTray>
            
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Vstavi"/>
    </TabControl>
    <RichTextBox Name="box" Grid.Row="2" Background="LightBlue" GotFocus="RichTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="RichTextBox_LostFocus">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph Name="tekst">
                Vpiši tekst
                <Bold>tukaj</Bold> .
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock Name="status"/>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an empty fake TabItem with Header which contains nothing but Buttons:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="1 2 3 4 5 6">
        <Border Background="Aqua"/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="A B C D E F">
        <Border Background="Bisque"/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabItem.Template>

        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0">
                <Button Content="C L I C K" Margin="2" Padding="10,3" />
                <Button Content="H E L L O" Margin="2" Padding="10,3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>

        <Border Background="Chartreuse"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Buttons intercept mouse clicks and tab selection is not triggered.

[image: Header buttons]

Answer (score 1):

That is not as easy as it seems. What you essentially want to do is add controls and functionality to an existing control. In order o add the buttons to the tab strip, you have to create a custom control template, because that defines the appearance and visual states of a control. To add functionality to these buttons you would either have to create custom attached properties or create a custom control.

Personally I think that the cleaner way is to create a custom control for this scenario. To make it flexible, we create an area in the tab strip for additional content of any kind and even allow for defining a data template for it.

To start off, create a class that derives from `TabControl` and add dependendency properties for the content to be displayed and the optional data template for arbitary content.

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
   static MyTabControl()
   {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTabControl), new
         FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTabControl)));
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalTabStripContentTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(AdditionalTabStripContentTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyTabControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalTabStripContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(AdditionalTabStripContent), typeof(object), typeof(MyTabControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public DataTemplate AdditionalTabStripContentTemplate
   {
      get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(AdditionalTabStripContentTemplateProperty);
      set => SetValue(AdditionalTabStripContentTemplateProperty, value);
   }

   public object AdditionalTabStripContent
   {
      get => GetValue(AdditionalTabStripContentProperty);
      set => SetValue(AdditionalTabStripContentProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Create a style for the new tab control with the additional tab strip content by copying and adapting the default style of the `TabControl`, which can be [extracted using Blend or Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio).

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
<Style x:Key="MyTabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabControl}">
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabControl}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                  <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContent}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContentTemplate}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=headerPanel}" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <Border x:Name="contentPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
               </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                  <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                  <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                  <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                  <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

This style is almost the same as the default style. The difference is in the lines below. We use a `StackPanel` to add a `ContentControl` to the right of the tab headers panel and bind its content and template to the properties of our custom control. We also bind the `Height` of the content control to the tab headers panel, so it looks clean.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
   <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContent}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContentTemplate}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=headerPanel}" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

To conclude the style, create an implicit style, so it is applied automatically to all `MyTabControl`s in scope.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyTabControlStyle}"/>
```

Now replace the `TabControl` in your XAML with this one and add the tab strip content e.g.:

```
<local:MyTabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
   <local:MyTabControl.AdditionalTabStripContent>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Button Content="Razveljavi"/>
         <Button Content="Ponovi"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </local:MyTabControl.AdditionalTabStripContent>
   <!-- ...your other tab items. -->
</local:MyTabControl>
```

The cool thing about this is that you  can add any content here and [even data template it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The result:

[image: Result with StackPanel]

The only downside of this template is that tab header collapsing into multiple rows is not possible. If you replace the `StackPanel` from above with this `DockPanel`, you get a more responsive version, but it will have the buttons on the right border aligned permanently.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContent}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding AdditionalTabStripContentTemplate}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=headerPanel}" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"/>
   <TabPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The result in a normal sized window and a small window that forces a tab header collapse:

[image: Result with DockPanel]

[image: Result with DockPanel small]