# How to set the Horizontal Alignment of the Input Gesture Texts in Menus in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menubar, text-alignment

I'm making an application with WPF and have a `Menu`. In that menu, most of the items have keyboard shortcuts, or input gestures. How do I set the horizontal alignment of the text that displays the input gesture?

What I want:

[image: Target: Menu items with input gesture aligned to the right.]

How it looks:

[image: Actual: Menu items with input gesture aligned to the left.]

I have already looked this problem up, but I seem to be the only person who cares about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the horizontal alignment of the input gesture text, you have to adapt the control template of `MenuItem`. You can either create it from scratch or create a copy of the default style [using Blend or Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio). I recommend the latter. If you want to now more about the required parts and visual states of the `MenuItem` control, you can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

In the following, I extracted the default style and only the control template and resources that are actually needed to change the input gesture text alignment. The essential change is in the `menuGestureText` `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

As you can see, I set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right`. Here is the essential XAML markup needed:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="#FF999999"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background" Color="#0A000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border" Color="#21000000"/>

<Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
   <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
      <Grid Margin="-1">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
         <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Border}" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
            <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" Height="11" Width="10"/>
         </Border>
         <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
         <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
         <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
      </Trigger>
      <MultiTrigger>
         <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
         </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
         <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
      </MultiTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
   <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can use the style by referencing it as `ItemContainerStyle` in `Menu` or assign the style to `MenuItem`s.

```
<Menu ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
   <MenuItem Header="File">
      <MenuItem Header="New file" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
      <MenuItem Header="New template" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+N"/>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Another option is to create an implicit style that is applied automatically to all `MenuItem`s in scope.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
```

This is the result, the input gesture text is aligned to the right.

[image: Menu with input gesture text aligned to the right.]