# Insert Content from CheckBox template into TextBlock Text field

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate

I've created this template for a `CheckBox`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
 <Border x:Name="border" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource StandardButtonHoveredBackground}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3">
  <Grid>
   <CheckBox  Name="MyCheckboxTemplate"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckboxTemplate, Path=Content}" Foreground="{StaticResource StandardForeground}" FontSize="12" Background="{StaticResource StandardButtonBackground}"/>
   </CheckBox>
  </Grid>
 </Border>
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBorder}"/>
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBorder}"/>
   </Trigger>
 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Which is called like this:

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <CheckBox Name="PWCheckbox" Style="{StaticResource MyCheckbox}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="25" Content="Save Username" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="PWCheckbox_Clicked"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Resulting in this:

[image: My faulty TextBox.]

How must the template be changed to show the text of `Content="Save Username"` in the newly created `CheckBox` into `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckboxTemplate, Path=Content}" ...` in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding by name to the `Content` property will of course get the `TextBlock` itself, which is set as content of the `CheckBox`. Changing the `Text` binding to a [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) will solve the issue.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" .../>
```

However, it is odd to use a `CheckBox` in a control template for a `CheckBox` and you should not do that, e.g. for implicit styles this will not work (*infinite loop*). You should instead copy the default style and template and adapt them instead. You can extract the default style [using Visual Studio or Blend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599).

This for example is the default style for `CheckBox`, you can use it and adapt it to your needs.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
<Style x:Key="MyCheckbox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                  <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                     <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                     <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                  </Grid>
               </Border>
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```