# How can I pass a parameter to a DataTrigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a list of things that I'm displaying via `ItemsControl` where each Item is basically a card that can be clicked. Is there a way I can pass a parameter to a `DataTrigger` to show whether or not a card has been clicked and if it is clicked set the `Background` to another color?

Comment: There should be a view model item property that controls which Background is set. Either bind Background directly, or set it by a DataTrigger with a Binding to that property.

Comment: @Clemens So I should add like a "IsSelected" property to each item in my list inside my view model?

Comment: In order to distinguish a selected item from an unselected one, of course, there must be some property in this item.
And for your task, besides this, it is better to use ListBox instead of ItemsControl.
It already implements the selection of the selected item and getting it in the SelectedItem property (or SelectedItems for multiple selection mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] show whether or not a card has been clicked and if it is clicked [...]

You created a view of cards and want them to be selectable. An `ItemsControl` is does not support selection, but there is a control called [`Selector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector?view=net-5.0) that derives from `ItemsControl`, which is the *abstract* base type for items controls that need selection. Its derivatives include [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=net-5.0) and [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=net-5.0), which come with selection and highlighting out-of-the-box. In other words, do not re-invent the wheel, there are already more suitable controls that meet your requirements.

Types derived from `Selector` contain dependency properties for [`SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex?view=net-5.0), [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem?view=net-5.0) or [`SelectedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue?view=net-5.0), which makes it easy for you to bind them and create triggers. There is also an attached property [`IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.isselected?view=net-5.0) for item containers, which is exactly what you need to change the `Background` or any other property depending on the clicked or selected item.

In the following I will show you how to customize the appearance of `ListBox` items. You can do the same with a `ListView.` You can extract the default style and template for a `ListBoxItem` [using Blend or Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599).

As you can see below there are a few brushes, a focus visual and the style with control template and triggers. Adapt this style to meet your desired design. Look for the triggers that bind the `IsSelected` property.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
               </MultiTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Move these resources to a resource dictionary that is in scope of the controls where you want to use them, or simply copy them to the application resources to make them globally available. In order to apply the style, you have two options.

1. Use the `x:Key` and reference them as `ItemContainerStyle` in each `ListBox`.

   ```
   <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle}" .../>
   ```
2. Make the style *implicit* by removing the `x:Key`. Then it will be applied to all `ListBoxItem` in scope of the resource dictionary that contains it.

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   ```