# Button Rounded Corners and Disabled Trigger not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` `Style` for my buttons.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundButton">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The rounded corners work, but when the `Button` is disabled the color does not change.

```
<Button Width="140" Style="{DynamicResource RoundButton}"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding HasUnsavedOdpChanges}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger for `IsEnabled` does not work, because the tigger in the default `Button` template takes precedence over your custom style. You have to [copy the default style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599) and adapt it instead, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hmmm - talk about recreating the wheel to change a color. I will look into this and try it.  Thanks