# Overlapping elements and a RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a `RadioButton` with text inside, and when checked, it needs to turn red.

How would I create this in WPF XAML?

Something like this:

[image: RadioButton as a filled rectangle that turns red when checked with the text "CPE" on the first line and "03" on the second line.]

Comment: Read this article about  [how to make Custom Controls in WPF](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm), it will help you

Comment: Hello, would a toggle button work for you?

Comment: Hello , my backend is already typed for radio button , i may be able to try to change some things if you have any suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the appearance of controls, you have to edit their control template. The easiest way is to [extract the default style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599) (with its control template) in Visual Studio or Blend. From there, you can adapt it to your requirements. This is an example that - although not with pretty colors - should do what you want.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Background" Color="#995555"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Border" Color="#990000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsChecked.Background" Color="#FF0000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsChecked.Border" Color="#990000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsChecked.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Border" Color="#990000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Foreground" Color="#000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Background" Color="#993333"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Border" Color="#990000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Border" Color="#555555"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#999999"/>
<Style x:Key="MyRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                     <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Focusable="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsChecked.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsChecked.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsChecked.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.IsUnchecked.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Copy the style and the resources to any resource dictionary in scope of the control that you want to style and reference the style using `StaticResource` (or `DynamicResource` if you intend to change it at runtime).

```
<RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource MyRadioButtonStyle}" GroupName="MyGroupName" Content="First"/>
```

If you want it to be applied automatically within the resource scope, remove the `x:Key` to make it a so-called *implicit style*. Since you specifically asked for a `RadioButton` style, I guess there are multiple exclusive options. If there are no exclusive options, mabe a `Checkbox` or a `ToggleButton` would be a better fit, you decide. Templating those controls would be done the same way: Extract, adapt, use and have fun.