# wpf ComboBox ISelectionBoxHighlighted problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight

When i select the combobox item, the selected item text highlighted with blue color.

How can i remove that highlight. But it is working after i removed trigger "IsSelectionBoxHighlighted = true" in epression blend.

But i have to do this thing in code behind in wpf with c# code?

I tried like this

```
com_image.IsSelectionBoxHighlighted = true;
```

but it is not work, it is showing exeption.

pls help me....

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278144/wpf-set-combobox-selected-item-highlight-color

Answer (score 1):

> You can not set

```
com_image.IsSelectionBoxHighlighted's
```

> value . It is read only property.

You can just get it;s value.

```
bool result= com_image.IsSelectionBoxHighlighted;
```

It will compile.